# Select code window after compiling

Tags: visual-studio

When I am working on a project and compiling all the time, it gets very annoying having to select the code window with the mouse each time after compiling, is there a keyboard shortcut in visual studio to select the code window?

Answer (score 1):

Back when I used Visual Studio, the <kbd>F4</kbd> key went to the next error location in the code and automatically selected the code window. Also try <kbd>Esc</kbd>. I think the "next error" keystroke is different in more current versions of VS, so use whatever your keyboard mapping offers.

Answer (score 0):

If you press Alt+W, then Visual Studio opens a list with open windows. You can then select the number corresponding to the window you want to activate. For example, Alt+W,1 activates the first window in the list.